# instaling uTorrent: No such file or directory

Tags: utorrent

I constantly get this error, any ideas?

```
rainmaker@Rain:~/Downloads$ sudo tar xvzf utorrent-server-3.0-25053.tar.gz -C /opt
tar: /opt: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: I suggest you try qBittorrent. It can be found in the Software Center, and it's better supported. It feels very much like µtorrent since qBittorrent aims to be a Free Software alternative.

Comment: Why not use transmission?

Comment: You sure that `/opt` exist?

Answer (score 2):

> tar: /opt: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Probably `/opt` doesn't exist, run:

```
sudo mkdir /opt
```

to create it and try again.